# Calculate with Values from Database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm better at design but i need to do this and cant figure it out how to do it so ill explain the problem:

So I have this table:

[image]

And this one:

[image]

1. I want to do is to calculate the sum of the `iliquido` from the 1st table and put the result at `total_iliquido` form the 2nd table where `id_proposta` is equal in both tables;
2. Take the values from `total_iliquido` and calculate with `desconto` (discount) and put the value on subtotal;
3. Take subtotal value and calculate with iva and put the result in total;

And that it can someone explain me how to do it please, really need your help guys. So as required here it is the Struct of database:

1st table:

[image: img]

2nd table:

[image: img]

And the connections I made:

[image: img]

So thats all i hope it help.

Comment: `programation` Nice new term

Comment: It would be rather helpful if you could provide the table structure(s) and example records as sql statements (something like `CREATE TABLE soFoo (...)` and `INSERT INTO soFoo ...`) instead of external images. Makes it a lot easier to test. Your sql frontend can surely export the data as such statements.

Comment: Have you tried to write any code so far? If so: share it and we'll give you some thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't test this, but you might get the idea.

```
UPDATE table2 t2
INNER JOIN(
   SELECT id_proposta, SUM(iliquido) as total
   FROM table1
   GROUP BY id_proposta
) x ON table2.id_proposta = table1.id_proposta
SET table2.total_iliquido = x.total, 
    table2.subtotal = table2.total_iliquido-table2.discount, 
    table2.total=table2.subtotal+table2.iva
```

**EDIT:**

To execute this query using php, you can use the following code:

```
<?php
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
    if (!$link) {
        die('Fail: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo 'Success';

    $query = "...";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$result) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: could u help me further, im kinda newbie at programation i kinda dont know where to put that code because im using dreamweaver and for dreamweaver theres no need to know about code he put all alone just with a few clicks, so help please so i can be better at programation and could evolve. Thanks.

Comment: oh ok cool already put the code all together and it says "No database selected" how do i fix this? And btw the database is called quatrotel and the table 1 is called proposta_print and the 2nd table is called propostas. Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Maybe you should have waited to ask your question, as you seemed to have skipped PHP + MySQL 101.

Comment: I guess i already connected to database but know hes giving a error "Column 'total' in field list is ambiguous" cant fix this one, help please.

Comment: I modified the query. Try it now.

Comment: ok already tested it give this error: SuccessInvalid query: Unknown column 'proposta_print.id_proposta' in 'on clause' btw this when it works when i refresh the page the values will be auto defined at propostas (table 2) table? PS:What i want is that the user inserts data to iva and discount and the other ones will be automatically inserted

Comment: You should read a few tutorials about MySQL and PHP and then you will know how to fix these problems yourself and make it do what you want. I can't post your entire script here.

Comment: ok thanks could you recommended a few ones? but i guess i wont be able to do it i need this done in a week.

Comment: What you want to do can be done in a week. You can find everything you need on w3schools: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/ and http://www.w3schools.com/php/

Comment: I would also appreciate if you could upvote the question or the comments that helped you :)

Comment: cant upvote requires level 15 sorry anyways already did the fix on your code :) Heres the correct one with a few arrangements. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE propostas t2
INNER JOIN(
   SELECT id_proposta, SUM(iliquido) as total
   FROM proposta_print
   GROUP BY id_proposta
) x ON t2.id_proposta = x.id_proposta
SET t2.total_iliquido = x.total, 
    t2.subtotal = t2.total_iliquido*t2.desconto/100, 
    t2.total = (t2.subtotal*t2.iva/100)+t2.subtotal
```

A fix for the one on the top, Thanks for your help Stefan Manciu.